# JS Showing Div Taking 2 Clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to show a div with JavaScript, but as the title says, it is taking 2 clicks to show.
Here's the code I am using, and the JS is being called with a `<script>` tag on the same file:

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>

<div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search">
  <input type="search" name="">
</div>

<button class="search-btn" id="mobile-search-button" onclick="show_search()">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>

<style>
  .mobile-search {
    display: none;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var mobile_search = document.getElementById("mobile-search");

  function show_search() {
    if (mobile_search.style.display === "none") {
      mobile_search.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      mobile_search.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

As you can see, it is taking 2 clicks to show the div, and I want it to be only 1. What is going on?

Comment: The `.style` property doesn't return styles inherited from CSS. Use `getComputedStyle()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to click the button twice because when you click the button for the first time, following condition

```
mobile_search.style.display === "none"
```

is `false`. This is because [`Element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ElementCSSInlineStyle/style) property returns [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) object which contains a list of styles that are added on the element using the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style) attribute. In other words, it returns the inline CSS styles set on the element. In your code, since you haven't added the `display: none` style using inline CSS, initial value of  `mobile_search.style.display` is not what you expect it to be.

So, on first click, the `else` block executes, setting `display` to `none` and when you click for the second time, above mentioned condition evaluates to `true` and the `input` element is displayed.

#### Solution

You have couple of options to solve the problem:

- Add `display: none` as an inline-style on the `#mobile-search` element.

  ```
  <div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search" style="display: none;">
     <input type="search" name="" />
  </div>
  ```
- Use [`Window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get the value of the `display` property.

  ```js
  var mobile_search = document.getElementById("mobile-search");

  function show_search() {
    if (window.getComputedStyle(mobile_search).display === "none") {
      mobile_search.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      mobile_search.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .mobile-search {
    display: none;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

  <div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search">
    <input type="search" name="">
  </div>

  <button class="search-btn" id="mobile-search-button" onclick="show_search()">
      <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </button>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The style property doesn't return styles from CSS. According to your condition when you are clicking the button it's adding display: none, after clicking the second time it's adding display: block, that's why you need to click twice to show the div.

You can try this in two ways.

**Step 1:** Just toggle block and none on click function

```js
var toggle  = document.getElementById("mobile-search-button");
var content = document.getElementById("mobile-search");

toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  content.style.display = (content.dataset.toggled ^= 1) ? "block" : "none";
});
```

```css
.mobile-search {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search">
  <input type="search" name="">
</div>

<button class="search-btn" id="mobile-search-button">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

**Step 2:**

You don't need any css, add styles to your input box.

```js
var mobile_search = document.getElementById("mobile-search");

  function show_search() {
    if (mobile_search.style.display === "none") {
      mobile_search.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      mobile_search.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search" style="display: none">
  <input type="search" name="">
</div>

<button class="search-btn" id="mobile-search-button" onclick="show_search()">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

**Step: Extra**

You can do it much more in an easier way. Just toggle class onclick

```js
$("#mobile-search-button").on("click", function(){
  $("#mobile-search").toggle();        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search" style="display: none">
  <input type="search" name="">
</div>

<button class="search-btn" id="mobile-search-button">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you already have a class to hide `mobile-search`, why not toggle that :

```js
var toggle = document.getElementById("mobile-search-button");
var classes = document.getElementById("mobile-search").classList;

toggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  classes.contains("mobile-search") ? classes.remove("mobile-search") : classes.add("mobile-search");
});
```

```css
.mobile-search {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="mobile-search" class="mobile-search">
  <input type="search" name="">
</div>

<button class="search-btn" id="mobile-search-button">
    <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</button>
```